# Two TextCell inside ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin

I'm very new at Xamarin Forms and i try to learn with easy examples. Now i have masterdetailpage and i want to show menu items with ListView and Listview items like TextCells but when i write Xaml code like this i cant see menu items why?

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" Title="Master" Icon="menuicon.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <TextCell x:Name="a" Text="Page 1" TextColor="Black" Tapped="TextCell_Tapped"></TextCell>
                                    <TextCell x:Name="b" Text="Page 2" TextColor="Black" Tapped="TextCell_Tapped_1"></TextCell>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

Thanks for all
Enjoy coding!

Comment: a ViewCell can only have single child.  You can make that child a container like StackLayout, and place multiple controls inside of it.  And you cannot nest Cells within one another.  A ListView is also intended to be used as a data bound control.  If you want a list of hardcoded items, use a Table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an answer on this link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95645/two-textcell-inside-listview

My logic was wrong and i changed my way to solve problem. I use one TextCell with bindings and solve problem